# How to delete a file by extension in Python?

Tags: python

I was messing around just trying to make a script that deletes items by ".zip" extension.

```
import sys
import os
from os import listdir

test=os.listdir("/Users/ben/downloads/")

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(item)
```

Whenever I run the script I get:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cities1000.zip'
```

cities1000.zip is obviously a file in my downloads folder.

What did I do wrong here?  Is the issue that os.remove requires the full path to the file?  If this is the issue, than how can I do that in this current script without completely rewriting it.

Comment: os.listdir("/Users/ben/downloads/", this is not the full path, is it?

Comment: this is the full path

Comment: I guess you have to put the path and the filename together for deletion.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can set the path in to a `dir_name` variable, then use `os.path.join` for your `os.remove`.

```
import os

dir_name = "/Users/ben/downloads/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))
```

Comment: Note that it is bad practice to use dir as a variable name, so is file, as they are also built in functions. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: @borgr I rolled back all the edits, made a couple changes and `s/dir/dir_name/g`. Looks like I had `dir` from the beginning. That should not have been there, good catch.

Comment: Looks like `sys` is not necessary.

Comment: @IvanCastro yup. Thanks for the heads up. Changed.

Answer (score 13):

For this operation you need to append the file name on to the file path so the command knows what folder you are looking into.

You can do this correctly and in a portable way in python using the [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) command.
For example:

```
import os

directory = "/Users/ben/downloads/"
test = os.listdir( directory )

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove( os.path.join( directory, item ) )
```

Comment: You don't need to do `from os import listdir` as you're doing `os.listdir` anyways.

Comment: what's `import sys` for?

Comment: @DutA. It's useless, i'll edit it out. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11):

Alternate approach that avoids join-ing yourself over and over: Use `glob` module to join once, then let it give you back the paths directly.

```
import glob
import os

dir = "/Users/ben/downloads/"

for zippath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, '*.zip')):
    os.remove(zippath)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use `Pathlib`-- a modern way, like the following:

```
import pathlib


dir = pathlib.Path("/Users/ben/downloads/")
zip_files = dir.glob(dir / "*.zip")
for zf in zip_files:
    zf.unlink()
```

If you want to delete all zip files recursively, just write so:

```
import pathlib


dir = pathlib.Path("/Users/ben/downloads/")
zip_files = dir.rglob(dir / "*.zip")  # recursively
for zf in zip_files:
    zf.unlink()
```

Comment: In my case, the additional `dir` inside the `glob` call broke it.  This worked: `zip_files = dir.glob("*.zip")`.  Python 3.9

Answer (score 3):

Just leaving my two cents on this issue: if you want to be *chic* you can use `glob` or `iglob` from the [glob package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), like so:

```py
import glob
import os

files_in_dir = glob.glob('/Users/ben/downloads/*.zip')
# or if you want to be fancy, you can use iglob, which returns an iterator:
files_in_dir = glob.iglob('/Users/ben/downloads/*.zip')

for _file in files_in_dir:
    print(_file) # just to be sure, you know how it is...
    os.remove(_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
origfolder = "/Users/ben/downloads/"
test = os.listdir(origfolder)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(origfolder, item))
```

The dirname is not included in the os.listdir output.  You have to attach it to reference the file from the list returned by said function.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the directory to the filename

```
os.remove("/Users/ben/downloads/" + item)
```

EDIT: or change the current working directory using `os.chdir`.