# Deleting files from multiple folders

Tags: python

I wanted to delete files that had a .dcm extension from multiple folders.

Found a question similar to mine but it doesn't deal with having to loop through multiple folders, this was the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834731/how-to-delete-a-file-by-extension-in-python) found

```
import os

dir_name = "mainFolder"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))
```

Using this code gave me this error:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'mainFolder\\innerFile.dcm'`
of course its not found bec the path it should be deleting is this
`'mainFolder\innerFolder\innerfile.dcm'`

I have also tried (didnt work as well) using a very bad nested loop using a list containing names of the dcm files to compare them with every file found in each folder using this code:

```
listofnames=[] #has all file names 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mainFolder):
    for file in files:
      for name in listofnames
        if name == file:
           os.remove(name)
```

Comment: Remember that just because you're in Python, that may not make it the best or even easiest tool for the job. Making Python ask Windows to just run `del *.dcm /s` is almost certainly faster, and less code.

Answer (score 1):

os.walk will navigate a directory and all its subdirectories.

For each observed file, check its extension. If it matches the extension that you want to remove then join() the pathname components and call remove()

```
import os

dir_name = 'mainFolder' # ideally use an absolute path here
extension = '.dcm'

for root, _, files in os.walk(dir_name):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[-1] == extension:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete the file in the `test` folder. So your code may look like this :

```
import os

dir_name = "mainFolder"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, test, item))
```

By doing this, you add the the folder to the path and therefore the file is reachable.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, when I tried print(item) in the for loop it shows only the folders names without the files inside